# Why does huponexit not work in the following?

Tags: bash, sighup

Bash manual says

> If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt (see Section 4.3.2 [The Shopt
>   Builtin], page 62), Bash sends a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits.

Why does huponexit not work in the following?

In one interactive shell

```
$ shopt -s huponexit
$ sleep 4321 &
[1] 13816
$ exit
```

Then in the other shell

```
$ ps -j 13816
  PID  PGID   SID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
13816 13816 13728 ?        S      0:00 sleep 4321
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when an interactive **login** shell exits

is significant.

```
$ bash -l
$ shopt -s huponexit
$ sleep 120 &
[1] 24235
```

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> exits (with `logout`, instead of `exit` as in your example), and

```
$ ps -j 24235
  PID  PGID   SID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

The `sleep` was killed too.